# How to check compiler at compile time?

Tags: visual-c++, gcc

If I'm going to disable warnings specific to compiler say VC++ and run this:

```
#pragma warning( disable : xxxx )
```

on comeau or g++, how do i make sure the preprocessor won't be executed it?

Comment: Don't you mean at compile time: IMO the title is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect the MSVC compiler you can see if _MSC_VER is defined so you could do something like

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning( disable : xxxx )
#endif
```

[Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) gives information about predefined VS macros

Answer (score 2):

See [this resource](http://predef.sourceforge.net/precomp.html) for a list of macros to identify which compiler is being used. Use them as follows (for MS VC):

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning( disable : xxxx )
#endif
```